# Incorret syntax on MERGE statement

Tags: sql

I am trying to conduct a `MERGE` from a temp table into our regular table. However, SQL Server Management Studio shows an error on the `ZipCodeTerritory` table name in the `UPDATE` statement.

I haven't written a `MERGE` before, however I can't see anything wrong with the syntax below. Since the intellisense error reporting can pretty non-descriptive w/Management Studio, can anyone else see what's wrong with the query below?

```
MERGE INTO ZipCodeTerritory as Target
USING ZipCodeTerritoryTemp as Source
ON
Target.Id = Source.Id

WHEN MATCHED THEN

UPDATE ZipCodeTerritory SET Target.ChannelCode = Source.ChannelCode, Target.DrmTerrDesc = Source.DrmTerrDesc, Target.IndDistrnId = Source.IndDistrnId,
    Target.StateCode = Source.StateCode, Target.ZipCode = Source.ZipCode, Target.EndDate = Source.EndDate, Target.EffectiveDate = Source.EffectiveDate,
    Target.LastUpdateId = Source.LastUpdateId, Target.LastUpdateDate = Source.LastUpdateDate, Target.ErrorCodes = Source.ErrorCodes,
    Target.Status = Source.Status 
WHERE Target.Id = Source.Id

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN

INSERT INTO ZipCodeTerritory (ChannelCode, DrmTerrDesc, IndDistrnId, StateCode, ZipCode, EndDate, EffectiveDate, LastUpdateId, LastUpdateDate, ErrorCodes, Status) 
VALUES(Source.ChannelCode, Source.DrmTerrDesc, Source.IndDistrnId, Source.StateCode, Source.ZipCode, Source.EndDate, Source.EffectiveDate, Source.LastUpdateId, Source.LastUpdateDate, Source.ErrorCodes, Source.Status)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Check syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx), `Update` and `Insert` clauses are without table name. Also it is not `Merge Into` simple `Merge`.

```
MERGE ZipCodeTerritory as Target
   ...
WHEN MATCHED THEN    
   UPDATE SET Target.ChannelCode = Source.ChannelCode ...
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
   INSERT (Ch ...
```

Why? Table name is redundant because it is informed in `Merge` clause.